# SQL Query Needed?

Tags: sql

There are two tables and the table has columns as

```
emp    salary
A         10
B         20
C         20 
D         30
E         40
F         50
```

the result shoud be like that :

the same salary employee should be added and the salary added should displayed in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

select group_concat(emp), count(emp), sum(salary) as salary from table group by salary order by salary.

If two employees have the same salary, then this will sum their salaries, as you mentioned:

> "the same salary employee should be added"

Is that what you meant?

e.g.

```
mysql> select group_concat(employee), count(employee), sum(salary) as salary from sal group by salary order by salary;
+------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| group_concat(employee) | count(employee) | salary |
+------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| A                      |               1 |     10 |
| D                      |               1 |     30 |
| B,C                    |               2 |     40 |
+------------------------+-----------------+--------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```